# white noise when using bluetooth headphone

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, headphones

Ive tried all the solution suggested but still nothing helps besides reboot the system.
I know that its Ubuntu issue cause when I use with android there are no issues,
plus tried several applications so its not on that level as well.
important to note that its just started recently and wasnt like this before

Answer (score 0):

Changing the configuration to HFP fix the white noise but the sound quality is much worst than the A2DP:

[image]